# How can I install multiple versions of Android Studio in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: android-studio

I saw someone working on Android Studio 2.3 and 3.0 on the same 14.04 system.

How is it possible to install two versions of Android Studio on one Ubuntu system?

Answer (score 0):

That's the whole point of the `/opt` directory. Install from source the versions you want to work on into different directories (it is custom to include the version number in the directory). Like so:

```
/opt/android{version}/
```

And you can start both from the executable inside `/opt/android{version}/`
If you create a symlink

```
/opt/android
```

to

```
/opt/android{active_version}/{executable}
```

you can use "android" as a command to start that one.